# Javascript array grouped in 3's

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, rss

I'm trying to parse rss feed. 
But what I want to get is:

1) an array grouped in 3 elements. So I have different feed with only its own data grouped together - so it becomes easy to call.

Example : 
myArr = [{title, date, content}, {title,date,content}, ....... ]

2) How do I access this array and its elements from outside this function?

I used console.log just to show you guys an idea of what I'm trying to achieve here.
Thanks guys for helping!!

```
var parser = require('rss-parser');


function myFunc(){
    parser.parseURL('https://www.reddit.com/.rss', function(err, parsed) {
      console.log(parsed.feed.title);
      parsed.feed.entries.forEach(function(entry) {
        var items = [];
        items.push(entry.title, entry.pubDate, entry.content.split('src=')[1]);
        console.log("Title: " + items[0])
        console.log("Date: " + items[1])
        console.log("Content: " + items[2]);
        console.log(" +++++++++++++++ ")

      });
    });
};

myFunc();
```

========

OutPut I get :

```
+++++++++++++++
Title: Brave Floridian workers delivering pizza during hurricane Irma.
Date: 2017-09-10T23:57:01.000Z
Content: "https://b.thumbs.redditmedia.com/4B5QcikKMP8fU90wk6cpR99LSkppsvBIbo88j
4YgysY.jpg" alt="Brave Floridian workers delivering pizza during hurricane Irma.
" title="Brave Floridian workers delivering pizza during hurricane Irma." /> </a
> </td><td> &#32; submitted by &#32; <a href="https://www.reddit.com/user/Daului
gi51"> /u/Dauluigi51 </a> &#32; to &#32; <a href="https://www.reddit.com/r/Bikin
iBottomTwitter/"> r/BikiniBottomTwitter </a> <br/> <span><a href="https://i.redd
.it/wuu9mews85lz.jpg">[link]</a></span> &#32; <span><a href="https://www.reddit.
com/r/BikiniBottomTwitter/comments/6zbunz/brave_floridian_workers_delivering_piz
za_during/">[comments]</a></span> </td></tr></table>
 +++++++++++++++
Title: Redditor Provides Specific, Clear Instructions to Aid a User in Helping P
eople Hit By Hurricane Irma in the U.S. Virgin Islands
Date: 2017-09-11T04:30:26.000Z
Content: undefined
 +++++++++++++++
Title: A fellow Florida 501st member posted this on his Facebook
Date: 2017-09-11T00:04:25.000Z
Content: "https://b.thumbs.redditmedia.com/C1Putt8Dihjv31fxqqpwOD3NHMbEddkMUogsW
j4DHLA.jpg" alt="A fellow Florida 501st member posted this on his Facebook" titl
e="A fellow Florida 501st member posted this on his Facebook" /> </a> </td><td>
&#32; submitted by &#32; <a href="https://www.reddit.com/user/morgul702"> /u/mor
gul702 </a> &#32; to &#32; <a href="https://www.reddit.com/r/StarWars/"> r/StarW
ars </a> <br/> <span><a href="https://i.imgur.com/I4XCVOP.jpg">[link]</a></span>
 &#32; <span><a href="https://www.reddit.com/r/StarWars/comments/6zbvyq/a_fellow
_florida_501st_member_posted_this_on_his/">[comments]</a></span> </td></tr></tab
le>
 +++++++++++++++
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Promises allow you to access the results of an async function from outside of the callback. I believe this is what you are looking for:

```
var parser = require('rss-parser');

function myFunc() {
    return new Promise((resolve) => { // Promise to allow async access outside of the function
        parser.parseURL('https://www.reddit.com/.rss', (err, parsed) => {
            resolve(parsed.feed.entries.map(entry => ({ title: entry.title, date: entry.pubDate, content: entry.content.split('src=')[1] }))); // Mapping into objects of title, date and entry
        });
    });
};

myFunc().then((entries) => {
    console.log(entries[0].title); // Output the title of the first result
    console.log(entries);
});
```

Comment: thank you! When I try to call : the below function with my res.render in expressjs to put the result on a web page. It does not work because of the then(). I read that if I remove .then() , then it gets unlinked with the Promises.  Is there a way to call this function inside res.render  Example:

Comment: Example:
`app.get('/', function(req, res){`
    res.render('index',{
    title: 'My App',
    myFunc().then((entries) => {
        console.log(entries[0].title); // Output the title of the first result
        console.log(entries);
    });
    items: [
      {id:1, Title1: (entries[0].title)},
      {id:2, Title2: (entries[1].title)},
      {id:3, Title3: (entries[2].title)}
    ]
  });
});`

Answer (score 1):

If I understood you well

```
const items = parsed.feed.entries.map((entry) => ({
    title: entry.title,
    date: entry.pubDate,
    content: entry.content.split('src=')[1],
}));
```

You are gonna get something like `items = [{title, date, content}, {title,date,content}, ....... ]`